# Why is this SQL Query unable to aggregate the Routes and sum functions?

Tags: sql, concatenation

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    subscriber_type,
    CONCAT( start_station_name, " to ", end_station_name ) AS Route,
    COUNT(*) AS num_trips,

FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.bikeshare_trips`

GROUP BY
    Route,
    num_trips
```

Here are the columns from my dataset:

- `subscriber_type` (either temp or subscriber)
- `start_station_name`: list of stations from which bike trips start
- `end_station_name`: list of stations from which bike trips end
- `Route`: my query that combines the start stations with the end stations of each trip
- `num_trips`: my query that attempts to return the total number of the newly created 'Route' column

the Error displayed:

> Column num_trips contains an aggregation function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [6:17]

Question: My logic was to group it by Route and num_trips to display the total number of trips for each route. Why is this incorrect?

Comment: You probably wan `GROUP BY subscriber_type, Route`. I find it helpful to look at each column in the `GROUP BY` clause as `per column A`. Your SQL reads "total trip per route per trip". That doesn't make any sense

Comment: You use aggregate function COUNT() for the column num_trips. If you want to group by num_trips, please write another join to get the count, and select from that join table